# How to test Nest.js services with mongoose orm?

Tags: mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to write a unit-tests to check my service, created with Nest.js and Mongoose. Jest is used as a test framework. It's not a problem to mock static model's methods like `find`, `exec`, et.c . But how to work with constructor?

i have the following code in service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { User, UserDocument } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    const user = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
    await user.save();
    return user;
  }
}
```

and the spec file below:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User, UserDocument } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
describe('UsersService', () => {
  let service: UsersService;

  let userModel: Model<UserDocument>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        { provide: getModelToken(User.name), useValue: Model<UserDocument> },
      ],
    }).compile();
    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
    userModel = module.get<Model<UserDocument>>(getModelToken(User.name));
  });

  it('should create a user', async () => {
    const createUserDto: CreateUserDto = {
      name: 'John',
      age: 25,
    };

    const result = await service.create(createUserDto);
    expect(result).toEqual(createUserDto);
  });
});
```

i got a following error at runtime:

```
 ● UsersService › should create a user

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree')

      10 |
      11 |   async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    > 12 |     const user = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
         |                  ^
      13 |     await user.save();
      14 |     return user;
      15 |   }

      at Model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$__setSchema (../node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3506:18)
      at Model.Document (../node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:89:10)
      at new Model (../node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:123:12)
      at UsersService.create (modules/users/users.service.ts:12:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (modules/users/users.service.spec.ts:29:34)
```

It's not a problem to mock static model's methods like `find`, `exec`, et.c . But how to work with constructor?

Comment: Does my answer solves your issue? If yes, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To mock the `constructor`, you can do something like:

```
{
  provide: getModelToken(User.name),
  useValue: {
    new: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({}),
    constructor: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({}),
    save: jest.fn(),
  },
},
```